# Не выполняется метод setViewValue адаптера

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-imageview

Всем привет.
Есть база данных SQLite и есть `ListView` для вывода ее значений. Необходимо в `ListView` (а именно в `ImageView`, находящийся в разметке элемента списка) вставить картинку, соответствующую значению поля таблицы. Соответствие определяет `HashMap`, который содержит идентификатор изображения(ключ) и строку (значение). Почитал как это делать при помощи метода `setViewValue` интерфейса `ViewBinder`, переопределил его и задал логику работы, однако правильного результата не добился - картинка не устанавливается. Не подскажите ли, в чем причина?

```
package ru.polpaketa.moneystat;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;


public class DayTab extends Fragment {

    ListView dayList;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor c;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    Binder binder;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day_tab, container, false);
        dayList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expList);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());

        binder = new Binder();


        Date dateNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

        c = dbHelper.getDayData(formatForDateNow.format(dateNow));

        String[] from = new String[] {DBHelper.COL_2, DBHelper.COL_3, DBHelper.COL_4};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvExp,R.id.tvCat,R.id.tvDate};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_item, c, from, to, 0);

        //Устанавливаем Binder
        adapter.setViewBinder(binder);

        //Устанавливаем адаптер
        dayList.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Обработка нажатия на элемент ListView
        dayList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExp);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private static class Binder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int i) {
            //Значение по умолчанию
            int imgLink = R.drawable.beach;
            if (view.getId() == R.id.imgHistCat) {
                //Текущее значение поля таблицы
                String item_content = c.getString(i);
                //Ищем подходящий ключ в HashMap
                for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> pair : ImageTextAdapter.imageTextMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (item_content.equals(pair.getValue())) {
                        imgLink = pair.getKey();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(imgLink); //Устанавливаем в ImageView соответствующую картинку
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас же в этом списке нет `ImageView`

```
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvExp,R.id.tvCat,R.id.tvDate};
```

Поэтому адаптер даже и не пытается ее байндить.

Comment: Справедливое замечание, спасибо.
Однако в таком случае не совсем понятно, как связать DBHelper.COL_3 с двумя view-элементами: с ImageView для картинки и с TextView, в который записать саму строку из бд.

Comment: Эти значения задаются для байндинга по умолчанию, а если вы для элемента проводите кастомный байндинг, так без разницы что там будет.

Comment: Изменил две строки и все заработало...
        String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_2, DBHelper.COL_3, DBHelper.COL_3, DBHelper.COL_4};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvExp, R.id.imgHistCat, R.id.tvCat, R.id.tvDate};
Еще раз спасибо за подсказку!